# What does the Worksheet.Cells Property do?

Tags: excel, vba

My First question is what does the Cells(i, 4) command do, that goes down through to Cells(i, 7).

```
Option Explicit

Sub batch1()
    Sheets("Batch").Activate
    Range("A1").Activate
    Dim name, office As String
    Dim q1, q2, q3, q4 As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 2


    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        DoEvents
        name = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1)
        office = ActiveCell.Offset(2, 1)

        q1 = ActiveCell.Offset(3, 1)
        q2 = ActiveCell.Offset(4, 1)
        q3 = ActiveCell.Offset(5, 1)
        q4 = ActiveCell.Offset(6, 1)

        Cells(i, 4) = name
        Cells(i, 5) = office
        Cells(i, 6) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(q1, q2, q3, q4)
        Cells(i, 7) = WorksheetFunction.Average(q1, q2, q3, q4)
        i = i + 1

        ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Activate
        ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Activate
    Loop

    Range("a1").Activate

End Sub
```

My next question is why do we have to .activate this sheet and the first cell, can't we just start spitting out the code without activating it, or is there something specific about this code that makes us have to activate it?

```
Option Explicit

Sub batchPractice()

    Dim name, place, weapon As String
    Dim iCount As Integer
    Dim candlestick, dagger, leadpipe, revolver, rope, wrench As Integer
    iCount = 1


    Sheets("BatchPractice").Activate
    Range("a1").Activate

        Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        DoEvents

            name = ActiveCell
            place = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)
            weapon = ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0)

            Cells(iCount, 3) = name & " in the " & place & " with the " & weapon
            iCount = iCount + 1

            If weapon = "Candlestick" Then
                candlestick = candlestick + 1
            ElseIf weapon = "Dagger" Then
                dagger = dagger + 1
            ElseIf weapon = "Dagger" Then
                dagger = dagger + 1
            ElseIf weapon = "Lead Pipe" Then
                leadpipe = leadpipe + 1
            ElseIf weapon = "Revolver" Then
                revolver = revolver + 1
            ElseIf weapon = "Rope" Then
                rope = rope + 1
            ElseIf weapon = "Wrench" Then
                wrench = wrench + 1
            Else
                MsgBox ("Unknown weapon: " & weapon)
            End If

            ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Activate
            ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Activate

        Loop

        Range("E2") = candlestick
        Range("E3") = dagger
        Range("E4") = leadpipe
        Range("E5") = revolver
        Range("E6") = rope
        Range("E7") = wrench

End Sub
```

Comment: Not one of your questions but this "Dim candlestick, dagger, leadpipe, revolver, rope, wrench As Integer" is wrong. This does not declare all of the variables to integers. It only declares wrench, the other variables are declared as being variants.

Comment: No offence but that first code loop is such a mashup of two methods that it is hard to make sense of without seeing some sample redacted data together with expected results. You should be incrementing the row with `i` or relying on two `.End(xlDown)` to transverse sections of data but not both. I fail to see how that is providing anywhere near the correct results.

Answer (score 3):

**1) What does `Cells` do?** 
The Cells property gets/sets the data from the cell you have specified. In your example:
`Cells(i, 4) = name`, you are trying to put the name in the row we're looping through (i), and column 4.

[Cells Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx)

**2) Why do we have to `.activate` this sheet and the first cell, can't we just start spitting out the code without activating it?**

At the moment this script is pulling data from the "Batch" sheet, so it activates to only focus on that specific worksheet. Usually, if you don't specify a sheet VBA will use the sheet that was last activated.

The cell is activated because it then starts to use specific cells near it with things like`ActiveCell.Offset(2, 1)`, so 2 rows down from A1, and 1 column across. The same could be achieved by using `Range("C2").Value` or `Cells(3, 2).Value` as it doesn't actually seem to change value.

I suggest that you take a few lessons online, I used YouTube as a quick crash course in VBA. I found it the easiest language to pick up.

Comment: Deleting my answer as this one is MUCH better.

Comment: There is no point in activating the sheet, though, using something like `With Worksheets("Batch").Range("A1")` (or specifying what worksheet you work with continuously through the code) is less likely to create errors if the macros get more complicated.

Comment: I agree when things start getting more complicated. But in this scenario activating the sheet is as good, and probably a good start in learning the basics of Vba.

Answer (score 1):

Dim as the variables correctly, if you leave a variable blank, then it becomes a variant.

If you start the code correctly, you won't have to activate or select anything.

Here is an example of your 1st code. You can run it from anywhere in the workbook.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim name As String, office As String, i
    Dim q1 As Double, q2 As Double, q3 As Double, q4 As Double

    Set sh = Sheets("Batch")
    With sh
        Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rws, 1))

        For Each c In Rng.Cells
            name = c.Offset(0, 1) & " " & c.Offset(1, 1)
            office = c.Offset(2, 1)
            i = c.Row
            q1 = c.Offset(3, 1)
            q2 = c.Offset(4, 1)
            q3 = c.Offset(5, 1)
            q4 = c.Offset(6, 1)

            .Cells(i, 4) = name
            .Cells(i, 5) = office
            .Cells(i, 6) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(q1, q2, q3, q4)
            .Cells(i, 7) = WorksheetFunction.Average(q1, q2, q3, q4)

        Next c
    End With

End Sub
```